# GCP - error "External IP Address already in use" when updating network interface of a vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, nic

I want to change the network interface of a vm.

1. Created a new vpc network **network-A** with **subnet-A**
2. Stopped the vm.
3. Edit the *vm instance* details to change from *default* to **network-A**
4. There is a drop down option to *create external IP address*
5. Created one **network-A-ext-IP**
6. Clicked Save
7. Error: ...***"External IP address already in use"***
8. VM not updated

I checked under the **external IP address** page, **network-A-ext-IP** is not attached to any vm and it is not in use.
I couldn't update the vm instance with the new network.

I am relatively new to GCP, I don't understand this behaviour. Can someone help to shed some light on this?

Comment: It's not normal. Did you try to create an external IP address first and then attach it to your VM? Create your IP in the same region as your VM.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes. VM, Network and IP are in the same region. I tried to create an external IP address first. I got the same error when I select the already created external IP from the drop down option.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot attach an existing (and not being used by other VM) [static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) to a new (or existing) VM is not normal and possibly a bug. This should not happen.

In this case I recommend for you to contact GCP Support (paid service) or file a bug on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).

You can try doing the same thing in another zone and see if it works. In any case filing a bug is a good idea.